# Error in Curl : Operation timed out after 1000 milliseconds

Tags: r, curl, timeout, quantmod

While using the Quantmod library in R, I've hit this error. Does anyone know why this could happen?

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(cu, handle = h) : 
  Timeout was reached: [finance.yahoo.com] Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

Here's the command that I ran.

```
goog <- getSymbols("GOOG")
```

Comment: Temporary network glitch? Firewall? Corporate proxy outage? DNS delays? Throttling or rate-limiting? My guess is that it's one of the first two. Can you do any other `httr` actions? Can you use `curl` on the (non-R) command line?